# Group function with "partition by" still duplicate values

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to sum some values from one column (total_stake) based on the second column (node_id) and group results by node_id. Right now it sums everything perfectly but it's still duplicate rows with the same node_id and summed value and I don't fully understand why.

Here is my query:

```
WITH events AS (
    SELECT n.id as node_id, n.event_time FROM nodes n
)
SELECT
    node_id,
    sum(total) FILTER (WHERE prior_to=0 OR prior_to=2) OVER (PARTITION BY node_id) as node_total_previous_days,
    sum(total) FILTER (WHERE prior_to=1) OVER (PARTITION BY node_id) as node_total_same_day,
    sum(total) FILTER (WHERE prior_to=2) OVER (PARTITION BY node_id) as node_total_previous_day,
FROM (
    SELECT e.node_id,
           n.total,
           CASE
               WHEN date_trunc('day', np.event_time) - INTERVAL '1 day' = date_trunc('day', np.placed_time) THEN 2
               WHEN date_trunc('day', np.event_time) - INTERVAL '1 day' > n.placed_time THEN 0
               WHEN date_trunc('day', np.event_time) = date_trunc('day', n.placed_time) THEN 1
               end as prior_to
    FROM events e
    JOIN net_parts np on np.node_id = e.node_id
    JOIN nets n ON n.id = np.net_id) as summary
GROUP BY node_id, total_stake, prior_to ORDER BY node_id;
```

Result of the query is:

```
node_id | node_total_previous_days | node_total_same_day | node_total_previous_day | 
---------+--------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
 6194 |                          |                     |                    3.00 |
 6187 |                          |               60.00 |                  200.00 |
 6305 |                   150.00 |              569.00 |                         |
 6305 |                   150.00 |              569.00 |                         |
 6305 |                   150.00 |              569.00 |                         |
 6305 |                   150.00 |              569.00 |                         |
 6305 |                   150.00 |              569.00 |                         |
```

And the question is, how to get grouped result without duplicated values? And to good understand it, why it duplicate that values?

Comment: This only helps with the original data. Maybe you could minimize your query since it is hard to analyze such huch queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` to determine the rows you want.  If you want one row per `node_id`, then use:

```
GROUP BY node_id
ORDER BY node_id;
```

Your additional `group by` keys are generating more rows.  You would see the additional values if you included `total_stake` and `prior_to` in the outermost `select`.